# sails-rabbitmq adapter integration with mongodb issue

Tags: rabbitmq, sails.js

I have setup a sailsjs project and trying to access rabbitmq using sails-rabbitmq adapter. I have followed https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-rabbitmq .
I want to use mongodb with rabbitmq. problem is when i 'sails lift' i get this error.

> error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load! 
>   error: Error: One of your models (`message`) refers to multiple datastores.
>   Please set its configured datastore to a string instead of an array in its model definition (`.connection`) or the app-wide default (`sails.config.models.connection`)
>   (this is conventionally set in your `config/models.js` file, or as part of your app's environment-specific config).
>
> > ```
> > at constructError (C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\construct-error.js:57:13)
> > at validateModelDef (C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\validate-model-def.js:97:11)
> > at C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\initialize.js:218:36
> > at arrayEach (C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\lodash\index.js:1289:13)
> > at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3345:13)
> > at Array.async.auto._normalizeModelDefs (C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\initialize.js:216:11)
> > at listener (C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:605:42)
> > at C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:544:17
> > at _arrayEach (C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:85:13)
> > at Immediate.taskComplete (C:\Users\demoapp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:543:13)
> > at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
> > ```

I have >  `connection: [ 'rabbitCluster', 'regularMongo' ]`
in my Message model. regularMongo is mongodb connection. Please let me know what other configuration i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

With following config I do not see any error. In `sails.config.models` set

```
module.exports.models = {
   connection: 'someMongodbServer',
   migrate: 'safe'
};
```

in `Message.js` set

```
module.exports = {
  connection: [ 'rabbitCluster', 'someMongodbServer' ],
  routingKey: [ 'parentMessage' ],
  attributes: {
    title: 'string',
    body: 'string',
    parentMessage: {
      model: 'message'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Your sails Version ?

Comment: "sails": "~0.12.4"